# Put coordinates from .txt file to Javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps, coordinates, google-maps-markers

I got txt file with such coordinates:

```
21.178797 56.888384
21.373250 56.588044
24.136921 56.965521
26.231814 56.858971
24.123382 56.951146
25.399601 57.540989
24.542900 57.090442
```

I need to put them in this type of array :

```
var locations = [
 ['Title A', 3.180967,101.715546, 1],
 ['Title B', 3.200848,101.616669, 2],
 ['Title C', 3.147372,101.597443, 3],
 ['Title D', 3.19125,101.710052, 4]
 ];
```

So i can put multiple markers using loop like so :

```
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
markers = new google.maps.Marker({
     position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
     map: map
     });

     google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(markers, i) {
     return function() {
         infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
         infowindow.open(map, marker);
     }
})(marker, i));

  }

}
```

Any ideas how i can make it work?

Thanks!:)

Thanks for your quick response guys.

I'll make it a little bit simplier for myself(it's my firs expirience using JS)

I have same file :

```
21.178797 56.888384
21.373250 56.588044
24.136921 56.965521
26.231814 56.858971
24.123382 56.951146
25.399601 57.540989
24.542900 57.090442
```

And i need array to look like that :

```
var locations = [
[3.180967,101.715546],
[3.200848,101.616669],
[3.147372,101.597443],
[3.19125,101.710052]
];
```

Thanks in advance)

Comment: Is the file on the server?  Or a local file the "user" will load from their machine?

Comment: Right now it is in the same folder with .js file(on machine),i'm getting coordinates from Api using Python and i put them into txt file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Parsing the data**

Use `String#split` to split the text into an array of lines, and then to split each line to an array:

```js
var str = `21.178797 56.888384
21.373250 56.588044
24.136921 56.965521
26.231814 56.858971
24.123382 56.951146
25.399601 57.540989
24.542900 57.090442`;

var result = str.split('\n').map(function(line, index) {
  return ['Title ' + String.fromCharCode(index + 65)].concat(line.split(' '));  
});

console.log(result);
```

**Getting the data**

Depending on the browsers you plan to support, you can [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) or the newer [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch). This simple method will use `fetch` if it can, and fallback to `XMLHttpRequest`:

```
function getData(path, cb) {
    var oReq;

    if (window.fetch) {
        window.fetch(path)
            .then(function(response) {
                return response.text();
            })
            .then(cb);
    } else {
        oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
        oReq.addEventListener("load", function() {
            cb(this.responseText);
        });
        oReq.open("GET", path);
        oReq.send();
    }
}

function parseData(data) {
    var coo = str.split('\n').map(function(line, index) {
        return ['Title ' + String.fromCharCode(index + 65)].concat(line.split(' '));  
    });

    // your code that uses coo
}

getData('coo.txt', parseData);
```